# Is debugger feature only supported by Amzi! prolog Commercial version?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, prolog, version, amzi-prolog

I installed Eclipse Neon + Amzi! Prolog (win64+10.0.4) a few days ago.
But when I tries to debug my prolog program, the IDE cries "This feature is not available in the edition you are running ..." with a "Yes" button to redirect to a webpage seems out of date.
Since debugging is a basic feature of a programming language, I doubt the real reason that I can not use the debug feature is my configuration, but not the version.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reported the problem to Amzi's prolog's official site and they published a new version of that to solve it.